# Model changes updating View-Model WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am having an issue getting my model changes updated back into my viewmodel so i can display. In this example i have a label and a button, when i press the button it will execute some business logic, and should update the label on screen. However, when my model changes the view will not. Any Idea on what i am doing wrong here?

View-

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:ViewModel>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    <Button Command={Binding UpdateBtnPressed}/>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel

```
public ViewModel()
{
    _Model = new Model();
}

public string Name
{
    get{return _Model.Name;}
    set
    {
        _Model.Name = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Name");
    }
}

public ICommand UpdateBtnPressed
{
get{
_UpdateBtn = new RelayCommand(param => UpdateLabelValue());
return _UpdateBtn;
}

private void UpdateLabelValue()
{
    _Model.Name = "Value Updated";
}
```

Model

```
private string name = "unmodified string";

public string Name
{
    get{return name;}
    set{name = value;}
}
```

Comment: Your `UpdateBtnPressed` method/property seems to be a bit messed up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void UpdateLabelValue()
{
  Name = "Value Updated";
}
```

Comment: Good spot. By updating the model directly they are bypassing the notification of the property change.

Comment: This would work, but i'm trying to simulate the case where the model would get updated not in the viewmodel directly. Such as other classes potentially business logic. I just stuck it in view model for this example.

Comment: In that case, implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface in the model and expose Model property in your ViewModel.

Comment: So you will still have to call some sort of global model refresh? You can't have the binding automatically refresh?

Comment: If your model is being updated by a source other than the ViewModel then the model will also need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Additionally your ViewModel will need to listen to the model's PropertyChanged event and react appropriately when a change is detected (i.e. raise a corresponding PropertyChanged for the ViewModel property.

Comment: If you want to use the binding, you need a way to notify the UI about the changes made to the binding value. 

In your case, binding source for label Content property may be:

a) Model (implements INPC)
ViewModel exposes property of type Model.
New binding: <Label Content="{Binding Path=Model.Name}"/>
After changing value of property Name of Model object, the binding automatically refresh (because Model impl. INPC).

b) ViewModel, exposes Name (as in your example)
Property Changing of the model will not lead to binding automatically refresh (because binding source ViewModel but not Model)

Comment: Thanks, I think i understand. I've got both subscribing to INPC events and binding to model through the ViewModel. Thanks Memoizer and Duane!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've missed to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface.

Answer (score 1):

Your model must implement INotifyPropertyChanged such as;

```
public class Personel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; OnChanged("Name");}
        }


        void OnChanged(string pn)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pn));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Should the Model implement it? I thought only the VM should implement INotifyPropertyChanged.